# How detect which OpenGL texture formats are natively supported?

Tags: opengl, textures, windows

For example, how detect if my videocard doesn’t support "bgr8" and convert it to another format, such as "rgba8" in software mode.

UPDATE: Sorry for the confusion. This question more about situation when I set *internalFormat* in *glTexImage2D* to something like "bgra8" but videodriver internally convert data to another format, like "rgba8".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your question seems to confuse certain concepts, so let's take things from the top. This is the definition of the function `glTexImage2D`:

```
void glTexImage2D( GLenum target, GLint level, GLint internalformat, GLsizei width, GLsizei height, GLint border, GLenum format, GLenum type, void *data );
```

There are two things that you might call "texture formats". The first is the `internalformat` parameter. This is the *real* [format of the image](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Image_Formats) as OpenGL stores it. The `format` parameter [describes part of the format of the pixel data](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Pixel_Transfer#Pixel_transfer_arguments) you are providing with the `data` parameter.

To put it another way, `format` and `type` define what *your* data looks like. `internalformat` is how you're telling OpenGL to *store* your data. Let us call `format` and `type` the "pixel transfer format", while `internalformat` will be the "image format".

The image format of a texture can *never* be "bgr8". There is no GL_BGR8 image format enumerator. There *is* a GL_BGR enum, but that is for the pixel transfer format, not the image format.

Or to put it another way, your pixel data that you give OpenGL can be stored in BGR order. But the OpenGL implementation decides on its own how to actually store that pixel data. Maybe it stores it in little-endian order. Maybe it stores it big-endian. Maybe it just arbitrarily rearranges the bytes. You don't know, and OpenGL does not provide a way to find out.

<del>There is no way to tell if a particular set of pixel transfer format parameters matches how the OpenGL implementation will store them given the image format.</del>

There ***is a way*** to tell now. And by "now", I mean in OpenGL 4.3 and/or ARB_internalformat_query2. Coming to a graphics card near you:

```
GLenum format, type;
glGetInternalformativ(texture_target, GL_RGBA8, GL_TEXTURE_IMAGE_FORMAT, 1, &format);
glGetInternalformativ(texture_target, GL_RGBA8, GL_TEXTURE_IMAGE_TYPE, 1, &type);
```

`format` and `type` now have the implementation's preferred `format` and `type` for using `glTex(Sub)Image` calls to `GL_RGBA8` images. There are separate `format` and `type` queries for `glReadPixels` downloads.

There are [other queries you can make](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glGetInternalFormat).

If you don't have access to these, you can use some general rules of thumb that most hardware will adhere to:

- will store pixel data for 8-bit-per-channel data in BGRA order. So if you want to match the format with your pixel data, so as to more quickly upload texture data, you want to use `GL_BGRA` for the `format`, and `GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8888` or `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE` for the `type`.
- will not actually store 24-bit colors as 24-bits. It will always pad them out to 32-bits; the alpha will just be ignored when it reads the data. So if you want to match formats, always use `GL_BGRA` `format` with `GL_RGB8` image formats, even if you have to put dummy data in the alpha component.

Comment: I found also better use format GL_BGRA with internalFormat GL_RGBA http://http.download.nvidia.com/developer/Papers/2005/Fast_Texture_Transfers/Fast_Texture_Transfers.pdf

Comment: I would refrain from rebranding the internalFormat parameter as "image format", because it's equally confusing. Perhaps it makes sense to think of "internalFormat" as the "texture pixel format". The "format" and "type" parameter combination are the "source pixel format" (which is often an image, hence my comment). And then of course there is the GPU format, which is BGRA for integer type formats.

Answer (score 7):

Generally most hardware doesn't suport 3-component texture formats so in this specific example you can make a reasonably safe assumption that it's converted.  A 3-component OpenGL texture is actually 4-component in hardware but with the alpha component ignored/set to 255/whatever.

https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Common_Mistakes#Texture_upload_and_pixel_reads
(That "common mistakes" page is a goldmine - bookmark it now!)

For a more general case, glTexSubImage2D performance can give you a good indication of whether or not the upload must go through a software conversion path.  You'd go about this during program startup - just create an empty texture (via glTexImage2D with NULL data), then issue a bunch of glTexSubImage2D calls, each followed by a glFinish to ensure it completes.  Ignore the first one because caches/states/etc are being setup for it, and time the rest of them.  Repeat this for a few different formats and pick the fastest.

Another alternative - seeing as you've tagged this question "Windows" - is to create a D3D device at startup (just after you've created your window but before you init OpenGL) then use D3D to check for format support.  While OpenGL allows for software conversion to a valid internal format, D3D doesn't - if it's not supported by the hardware you can't do it.  Then destroy D3D and bring up OpenGL.  (This technique can also be used for querying other stuff that OpenGL doesn't let you query directly).

It's actually a useful rule of thumb to cross-check what you're doing in OpenGL with the D3D documentation.  If D3D can't do something then it can be a good indication that the something in question is not supported in hardware.  Not always true, but a useful starting place.